# android sliding up panel in my eclipse project showing error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, toolbar, slidingpanelayout

I have imported the gradle project in eclipse by single classes  it not showing any error but when i run app it shows me this error dex path error

Here is my logcat

```
   07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286): Process: com.sothree.slidinguppanel.demo, PID: 12286
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sothree.slidinguppanel.demo/com.sothree.slidinguppanel.demo.DemoActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.NativeActionModeAwareLayout
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2301)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5212)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.NativeActionModeAwareLayout
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:814)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:299)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:246)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at com.sothree.slidinguppanel.demo.DemoActivity.onCreate(DemoActivity.java:33)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5240)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2216)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    ... 11 more
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.internal.widget.NativeActionModeAwareLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sothree.slidinguppanel.demo-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.sothree.slidinguppanel.demo-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
07-09 12:42:55.984: E/AndroidRuntime(12286):    ... 24 more
```

and here is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DemoActivity" >

    <com.example.slidingpannel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
        sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
        sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
        sothree:umanoParalaxOffset="100dp"
        sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp" >

        <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                sothree:theme="@style/ActionBar" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="270dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Main Content"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/dragView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="68dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/name"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/follow"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:scaleType="fitStart"
                    android:src="@drawable/graphic" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

        <!-- SLIDING LAYOUT -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dragView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="68dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/follow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:src="@drawable/graphic" >
            </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.example.slidingpannel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

please help me i am stuck in since last two days.

Comment: have you added [Android Sliding Up Panel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) library?

Comment: Got it working, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36731172/troubles-with-androidslidinguppanel-with-eclipse-error-inflating-class

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with import of Android Sliding Up Panel Library.
Add `[Android Sliding Up Panel][1]` library in your project.

Simply add the following dependency to your `build.gradle` file to use the library:

```
dependencies {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.0.0'
}
```

then change this tag

```
com.example.slidingpannel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
```

to

```
com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
```

Comment: Bu i am using eclipse..  so how can i add dependency in build.gradle

Comment: Did you copied all files from https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/tree/master/library into eclipse?

Comment: changed package name of `SlidingUpPanelLayout` ?